# Can we detect the existence of outliers using Min and Max?

Tags: self-study, feature-selection, outliers

Suppose, I have a data set with eight features in my hand.

Data are normally distributed.

I have juxtaposed their mins and maxes row by row.

```
             f1        f2           f3        f4       f5      f6       f7          f8
 min       0.0000    0.0000         0         0         0   -0.0000   -0.0000    -0.0000
 max       0.0000    0.0001    0.0003    0.0038    0.0038    1.4530    0.0193     0.0002
```

Can we tell anything about the existence of outliers from these information?

Comment: Not based on this information solely

Comment: @Aksakal, what else do u need to know? Data are normally distributed.

Comment: If it's normally distributed, then there are no outliers. Right? To truly separate outliers you need to know the data, how it was collected. Pure stat tests are limited.

Comment: @Aksakal, am I the only one who is facing a lot of scary people everyday?

Comment: No, you're not "the only one who is facing a lot of scary person everyday". Perhaps, police officers and jail guards do too.

Comment: @whuber, and how is that duplicate?

Comment: It's the same question with the same purpose.  If you were to ask a series of cooking questions, for instance, along the lines of "How do I make pancakes blue?," "How do I make pancakes red?," "How do I make pancakes green?," *etc.*, and the answers to the first one stated that you only have to add food coloring, then nobody would tolerate the additional questions: they would add no new information and would merely reflect a failure to read and understand the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, no. Keep in mind that, as I think many people tend to forget, outliers, in the most general sense, are not a formal, mathematical phenomenon. They are just values that seem too far from the rest of the data, or too extreme, to be likely to be correct or useful. Our tag description for "outlier" puts it like this: "An outlier is an observation that appears to be unusual or not well described relative to a simple characterization of a dataset." So, you can't hope for any general-purpose mathematical method for outlier detection.

As for extrema (minima and maxima), these can certainly be useful for picking up some outliers. For example, if you have a variable that's supposed to be from a 5-point rating scale, and the maximum is 7, something's wrong. But not every outlier is an extremum.